# Read child nodes from parent node from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Under parent **Parameters** I have child **Parameter** as "Fruit" and "TransactionID". I want to read both the values of "Fruit" and "TransactionID".

xml code :

```
  <soap:Parameters>
    <soap:Parameter>
      <soap:Name>Fruit</soap:Name>
      <soap:Value>Apple</soap:Value>
    </soap:Parameter>
    <soap:Parameter>
      <soap:Name>TransactionID</soap:Name>
      <soap:Value>1111111</soap:Value>
    </soap:Parameter>
  </soap:Parameters>
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the [XDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A first parse the XML file using XDocument Class and then use Linq query to iterate over the Parent node

Comment: Use LINQ to XML

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
var parentNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("//soap:DataReq/soap:Extensions/soap:Extension/soap:Parameters", nsmgr);
```